# Show that 2 sets are not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

Prove that a closed interval $A=[0,1]$ and $B=\{(x,y)∈R^2 \mid ||(x,y)||≤1\}$ are not manifold

I'm struck with this problem.Can anyone explain how and what property should i use to show that for any open sets in A and B which contains boundary point is not homeomorphic to open set in $R$ and $R^2$ respectively

Comment: do you mean by your last sentence e.g. $[0,1/2]$ is not homeomorphic to $(a,b), a,b \in \mathbb{R}$? Or do you want $A$ and $B$ are not homeomorphic?

Comment: Only want to show that A=[0,1] isn't manifold and also B

Answer (score 2):

Consider an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $\mathbb R$. For simplicity assume $U$ is connected (i.e. replace it with a possibly smaller open ball). Then $U\setminus\{x\}$ is not connected. This property does not hold if $x$ is instead a boundary point of a closed interval.

A similar argument works in $\mathbb R^2$: For an interior point there exists a closed line $S^1\subset U\ni x$ that can be contracted in $U$, but not in $U\setminus\{x\}$. For a boundary point, this is not the case.